# Can I bind two methods to a WPF Control?

Tags: wpf

I have this combo box

```
    <ComboBox Height="23"
              SelectionChanged="comboBox1_SelectionChanged">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Opt1"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Opt2"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

Basically what I need is to run two methods, the one already bound (combobox1_SelectionChanged) and an additional one I created. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you can't do this declaratively. Use the `+=` operator in C#.

```
MyComboBox.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(method1);
MyComboBox.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(method2);
...
```

Answer (score 5):

I would probably just bind to 1 function and have that function call the common pieces of code.